# VARIANT_BOOL vs. BOOL

Tags: c++, com

I am writing a COM object in C++ using ATL and am not sure whether I should be using `VARIANT_BOOL` for my methods/properties or not.  The object will be called by other C++ apps but I cannot rule out usage from .NET.

I can stick to good old `BOOL` (which IIRC is simply an unsigned int) but as `VARIANT_BOOL` is there, shouldn't I be using it?  If I do use it, and call these methods from a C++ app, I have to add extra code as a `VARIANT_BOOL` is not like a 'normal' boolean and I have to check for `VARIANT_TRUE` and `VARIANT_FALSE` values.

Is `VARIANT_BOOL` an anachronism that I can forget or should I stick with it?

Comment: +1 Arul's answer. But in short, yes, use VARIANT_BOOL.

Comment: It's an OLE Automation data type. For C++ / MIDL one can also use the boolean type. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/midl-and-boolean-data-types

Answer (score 2):

VARIANT_BOOL will make your COM component VB6 friendly. COM never really seemed to be made for doing things simply in C++, but more focus on making it easy to use from VB. Not sure if this still applies to .net access of a COM component or not.